# scope of variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, scope, global

I am building an image gallery using php. The code I am using is like:

```
function ImageBlock() {
    $dir = 'img-gallery';
    $images = scandir($dir);
    $classN = 1;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if ($image != '.' && $image != '..') {
            echo '<img class="image' . $classN . '" src="img-gallery/' . $image . '" width="300px" 
                  height="300px">';
        }
        $classN++;
    }
}
```

if I call this function in another file it works. My question is if I use the cose below, declaring the variables out of function ...it does not work anymore:

```
$dir = 'img-gallery';
$images = scandir($dir);

function ImageBlock() {
    $classN = 1;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if ($image != '.' && $image != '..') {
            echo '<img class="image' . $classN . '" src="img-gallery/' . $image . '" width="300px"  
        height="300px">';
        }
        $classN++;
    }
}
```

Why, I mean a variable declared outside should have a global scope to my knowledge, and should ne accesible from within the function. Isn't it so ?

Comment: There is a [`global`](http://php.net/global) keyword for that cases.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not JavaScript. Functions in the global namespace are not available inside of functions unless you explicitly make them so. There are three ways to do this:

**Pass them as a parameter** (recommended)

```
function ImageBlock($images){
```

**Use the `global` keyword** (strongly not recommended)

```
function ImageBlock(){
    global $images
```

**Use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal** (strongly not recommended)

```
function ImageBlock(){
    $images = $GLOBALS['images'];
```

Comment: thank you very much . the confusion cleared